# fs_usage returns a LOT of ioctl lines

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystem

I've been reading up on interesting Terminal commands (I've used it forever, but there's always more to learn) when I ran across [this](https://serverfault.com/a/7353). I ran `sudo fs_usage` and got a whole lot of this:

```
...
13:39:09  ioctl                   0.000019   WindowServer
13:39:09  ioctl                   0.000017   WindowServer
13:39:09  ioctl                   0.000020   WindowServer
13:39:09  ioctl                   0.000018   WindowServer
...
```

I figure, if I ever actually need to use this, it would be nice to have a way not only to filter out filesystem activity related to the WindowServer, in particular, but other processes as well. It would also be nice to specify a service or process for which to return information.

Have I misread the usefulness of this function? Is there a way to get rid of those numerous WindowServer calls? Can I specify the processes in which I'm interested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that is possible by using fs_usage with several options. You may also pipe it to grep to further restrict the output.

To exclude a process or a pid (and also fs_usage itself) use the -e option:

```
sudo fs_usage -e WindowsServer
sudo fs_usage -e 123
```

Specifying the -f option turns on output filtering based on the mode provided.
The possible modes are:

```
network    Network-related events are displayed.  
filesys    Filesystem-related events are displayed.  
pathname   Pathname-related events are displayed.  
exec       Exec and spawn events are displayed.  
diskio     Disk I/O events are displayed.  
cachehit   In addition, show cache hits.
```

Example:

```
sudo fs_usage -e WindowsServer -f filesys
```

To just show a special pid/command and exclude all other, use the pid (enter `ps aux` to get it) or the name of the command or application

Examples:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys Terminal
sudo fs_usage -f filesys 178
```

A different possibility is to pipe the output of fs_usage to grep:

```
sudo fs_usage -e -f filesys|grep Terminal
sudo fs_usage -e -f filesys|grep -v grep|grep write
sudo fs_usage -e|grep -v grep|grep -v WindowsServer|grep ioctl
```

The part `grep -v grep` or `grep -v WindowsServer` excludes "grep" and/or "WindowsServer" from occurring in the result.

Sources:
[Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html)
[Rentzsch](http://web.archive.org/web/20091231090628/http://rentzsch.com/macosx/fs_usageIntro)